# Make ZF2 don't stop on division by zero query

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2, postgresql-8.4

My application builds dynamic reports created by the users, which may produce  queries that return division by zero.
When this happens ZF2 catches that with `Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidQueryException` to display the exception and stop my script.

I need to continue the script execution even when that happens, because the application will show `0` in those calculations and the report will still be shown.

I already disabled these settings in `config/autoload/local.php` and am sure the `global.php` isn't overwriting them:

```
'phpSettings'   => array(
    'display_startup_errors' => false,
    'display_errors'         => false,
    'error_reporting'        => 0,
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => false,
    'display_exceptions'       => false,
),
```

The script still stops and show my custom "error" page, the only difference is that it hides exception details.

How can I keep the script/application running even when the `division by zero` occurs?

I already saw other questions talking about `display_exceptions=false` but as you can see it didn't help me.

I would prefer a solution without making changes to the query creation process, because it is very complex, but am acepting all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just Capture the exception yourself by doing a try catch around the the query

```
try {
    // try to run the query that might throw the exception.
} catch (\Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidQueryException $e) {
    // do set the result to zero.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, have you considered testing if the denominator equals 0 **before** it is actually calculated ? If it is, you can skip the calculation and directly return a string or another number. That way you would avoid the *division by zero* error.

---

Example

```
function getStatistics($returned_value) {

    if ($returned_value  == 0) {

      //Cannot compute
      return "Impossible";

    } else {

      //Do the calculation
      return 100/$returned_value; //For example      

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't do that because the calculation is made by queries, which may return 0 or not.

Comment: If I understood properly and that the `division by 0` issue is thrown during the query creation, then you might want to apply this fix to the process that creates the query.

Comment: It is very hard because of the complexity of the query creation, I tried wrapping the whole calculation inside a `coalesce` but that didn't work as `division by zero` still happens.